# how to take a list of objects, cast it to a string, then return the string back to the method

Tags: java, sql, arrays, database, list

I currently have an application thats trying to get item id's from a database. It connects to a db, runs a select query alongside a provided "vin" number, obtains one column of information that contains item id numbers, takes the results and puts it into a list of objects. Now I need to find a way to take a list of objects, cast it to a string, then return the string back to the method.

My code:

```java
public String getItemId(String vin) {// method that accepts string parameter called vin
    Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(env.getProperty("item-id"));  //query q created
    q.setParameter("vin", vin); //set parameters
    List<Object[]> d = q.getResultList(); //takes results and puts into list of objects//

    String[] array = new String[d.size()]; //create array of strings, size determined by number of elements from d
    int index = 0;
    for (Object value : d) { //goes through each element in d which contains list of objects
        array[index] = String.valueOf(value); //adds to index, will accept values that arent just strings,
        index++; //keeps iterating until loop is done
    }
    return array[index];
}
```

I don't get any errors when I run the code, but when I go to see if any numbers are returned from the db via the webpage on localhost, I get a generic template error which usually means nothing returned.

Is my casting logic wrong? Or is there another way take a list of objects, cast it to a string, then return the string back to the method?

Comment: I don't see any casting. But if you're trying to convert `Object[]` to string you're going to need `Arrays.toString()` at minimum.

Comment: Does `Query#getResultSet` really return a list *of arrays* of objects, or did you mean it returns a list of objects?

Comment: The return statement `return array[index]` always throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`  because `index` is always one more than the size of `array`.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
String.join( " | " , strings )
```

Or, using streams:

```java
List
        .of( LocalDate.now() , "Bob" , new BigDecimal( "123.45" ) )
        .stream()
        .map( Object :: toString )
        .collect( Collectors.joining( " | " ) );
```

> 2022-05-27 | Bob | 123.45

## Your code works

Based on the rest of your code, this:

```
List<Object[]> d = q.getResultList();
```

… must be mistaken. Apparently `Query#getResultSet` returns a `List` of `Object` objects not really a `List` of arrays of `Object` objects as your code above declares.

Let's assume you meant:

```
List< Object > d = q.getResultList() ;
```

Your code actually works. I will substitute an `List` of `Object` objects.

```java
List < Object > d = List.of( LocalDate.now() , "Bob" , new BigDecimal( "123.45" ) );
```

And run your code.

```java
String[] array = new String[ d.size() ];
int index = 0;
for ( Object value : d )
{
    array[ index ] = String.valueOf( value );
    index++; //keeps iterating until loop is done
}
```

Dump to console.

```java
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( array ) );
```

We get this result.

> [2022-05-27, Bob, 123.45]

You asked:

> Is my casting logic wrong?

There is no [casting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) in your code.

You said:

> but when I go to see if any numbers are returned from the db via the webpage on localhost, I get a generic template error which usually means nothing returned.

This kind of confusion means you have stuck together too much code in one place. Separate logical chunks into separate methods. Then use unit testing to verify expected behavior.

In your current situation, the generating of text from a `List` of `Object` objects should be pulled out into its own method. Name that method something like `joinObjectsIntoAString`. Pass the `List< Object >` as an argument to that method. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

## Alternate approach

You asked:

> Or is there another way take a list of objects, cast it to a string, then return the string back to the method?

Yes, there are alternatives.

I would avoid dealing with an index.

We can get a textual representation of each object by looping each element, and calling its `Object#toString` method,

```java
List < String > strings = new ArrayList <>( d.size() );
for ( Object o : d )
{
    strings.add( o.toString() );
}
```

We can combine those produced `String` objects with a call to the `String.join` static method. Pass an argument for your desired delimiter.

```
String result = String.join( " | " , strings );
```

> result = 2022-05-27 | Bob | 123.45

### Streams

We can make that code more concise by using streams.

```java
List < Object > d = List.of( LocalDate.now() , "Bob" , new BigDecimal( "123.45" ) );
List < String > strings = d.stream().map( object -> object.toString() ).toList();
String result = strings.stream().collect( Collectors.joining( " | " ) );
```

We can even turn that into a one-liner.

```java
String result =
        List
                .of( LocalDate.now() , "Bob" , new BigDecimal( "123.45" ) )
                .stream()
                .map( object -> object.toString() )
                .collect( Collectors.joining( " | " ) );
```

And even shorter by using a method reference, `Object :: toString`.

```java
String result =
        List
                .of( LocalDate.now() , "Bob" , new BigDecimal( "123.45" ) )
                .stream()
                .map( Object :: toString )
                .collect( Collectors.joining( " | " ) );
```

See that [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/CID126).

> 2022-05-27 | Bob | 123.45